# Printing attributed string characters one by one in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, animation, nsattributedstring, nstextstorage

I have a custom UILabel class that allows me to attach tapGestureRecognizers to specific parts of a string. Now, I'm trying to animate the text of the UILabel to print one character at a time. My code seems to be adding one character at a time to TextStorage, but the text shows up all at the same time, without animation. Is adding one character at a time to TextStorage the wrong approach? Thanks

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
    var textStorage = NSTextStorage() {
        didSet {
            textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        }
    }
    var onCharacterTapped: ((_ label: UILabel, _ characterIndex: Int) -> Void)?

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
        didSet {
            if let attributedText = attributedText {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    for (index, char) in attributedText.string.characters.enumerated() {

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5 * Double(index)) {
                            print("character ch is: \(char) at index: \(index)")
                            let text = NSAttributedString(string: String(char))
                            self.textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: text)
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                textStorage = NSTextStorage()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not set the `attributedText` property with each bit of text?

Comment: I tried that, but I can't seem to figure out an equivalent to .append in this case. Before I decided to work with attributed strings it was as easy as self.text?.append(char)

Comment: Use `attributedSubstring` from 0 to `index`. No need to append.

Comment: Do you mean CFAttributedStringCreateWithSubstring(kCFAllocatorDefault, attributedText, range) ?

Comment: No, I mean `NSAttributedString attributedSubstring`

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the suggestion. That works, but it doesn't answer my question about creating a typewriter-like animation by updating TextStorage in a loop. TextStorage seems to only update all at once despite the loop.